# How do I have a .htaccess directory map to a get query, but still accept regular get queries?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've made a simple htaccess file to take the directory of a url and have it treated like a get query (somesite.uk/home is treated like somesite.uk/?page=home) but have noticed that it interferes with other get queries. (somesite.uk/home?group=testgroup is just treated like somesite.uk/home but I want that group query while on that specific page)

My current htaccess file:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z]+)$ index.php/?page=$1
```

If there a way I can keep using the directory as the page query, but still have regular queries work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add `QSA` flag to your rule. `QSA` (Query String Append) flag **preserves existing query parameters** while adding a new one.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z]+)/?$ index.php/?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```